# use different XSL templates when opening a XML in a new window

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, parameter-passing

I have an XML file which is rendered by a set XSL file (XSLT 1.0). The XSL file includes several other XSL files with multiple templates in them.
What I need to do is include a button in the rendered XML to open the same XML in a new window, using some different templates in the XSLs.
Including the button and opening a new window is not the problem, but how do I tell the XSL to use different templates because it got opened in a new window? My idea was to use JavaScript for opening the new window, but I don't see how I could set or pass a parameter to check on with XSLT/XPATH.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using querystrings. 
Upon loading opening my URL in a new window

```
window.open(window.location+'?a=1')
```

in the JS onload event I check if the querystring is empty

```
if(window.location.search=='')
```

if not I search for the links by class and remove the attributes

```
.removeAttribute('href');
.removeAttribute('onclick');
```

To clarify, the templates would simply have removed some links from the page. It was easier to simply remove them by JS than using different templates.

Answer (score 1):

Change the xml or transform server side (with php,asp,jsp...) or client side (with javascript). You can parameterize only the xsl processor, but not the xml file. If you don't want to use xsl processor, then you have to recreate the xml file on server side with same body and different header with another stylesheet.